retrieve google refresh token in keycloak
Keycloak, by default, does not forward tokens received from external Identity Providers (IDPs), such as Google. To access resources like the Google Calendar, it is necessary to obtain the refresh and access tokens sent by google.
I am trying to get the refresh token returned by google.
currently I am following the method of Retrieving external IDP tokens
which gets me the refresh token on first login and i am saving it in the database & it works fine.
   const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${keycloakAccessToken}`
      }
    }

    let response = await axios.get(`${process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER}/broker/google/token`, config)

however, I want to be able to retrieve this refresh token for the same user again because if same user logged in from a different client in same realm I will not be able to save the refresh token in the new client database
I have tried exchange token  however this retrieves only the access token
does keycloak save the refresh token returned by google in its db? is there an api to  retrieve it?
any help would be appreciated

after several trials, I ended up using the following work around:

create a custom attribute for the users
on first login I will capture google refresh_token and save it in the custom attribute
if i login with same google account to a different user i will take the refresh token from the attribute

